# WPF - How to not update layout when Visibility is Collapse

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am developing WPF, MVVM Application.
I have 30 views with complex layouts.
When I change view, Using the contentcontrol's datatemplate is slow to display.
So I'm preloading views and changing the visibility.
I was checking the application timeline, the ui thread is used about 99% for layout.
UI thread usage is normal when using ContentControl.
Is there a way to prevent collapsed views from recalculating their layout. Or is there a way to lower the utilization of the UI thread?

Thank you in advance to anyone who replies.

Comment: The layout must be calculated as collapsing an element removes it from the visual tree. So the layout has changed, new space is available. You should refactor your templates and view model classes. You seem to have serious design issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.